# Can custom web fonts affect SEO?

Tags: css, seo, webfonts, google-webfonts, custom-font

A web site I'm developing needs two custom font families using. There are close matches to these fonts on Google Fonts, but they aren't exact matches.

I have the ttf files for the two fonts, so can create them easily enough as my own custom web fonts, but I am wondering if using my own custom web fonts **(ie, rather than Google Fonts)** may have an adverse affect on SEO - as there is far less chance a browser would have my custom fonts cached, which would increase the average page load time.

Although my concern seems valid, I'm wondering if it is significant enough to actually be taken into account by search engines and, therefore, have an adverse effect on the site rankings?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, custom fonts affects loading speed, which in offers lower page ranking. Refer below

http://www.webilogy.com/2013/11/tips-uploading-custom-fonts-website/
http://blog.futtta.be/2011/01/07/website-performance-impact-of-web-fonts/

Answer (score -1):

Well if you look at the top 10k sites from Alexa, you can see how many of them use web fonts. It's an overwhelming majority, including not just copy fonts, but icon fonts like FontAwesome, which is THE most popular web font, pretty much, excluding OS fonts like Arial, Helvetica, Georgia. See the data for yourself here:

http://bonfx.com/fonts-of-the-world/

If there were penalties, which translate into lost revenue, we would not see widespread adoption. I would look for performance gains everywhere else to offset any potential slow down from using web fonts, but definitely keep your web fonts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my question was more to do with custom web fonts vs Google web fonts.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer is : No [well for the more description](http://advicesacademy.com/seo/font-size-search-engine-optimization-seo/)

Comment: Thanks, but that article as about font size.